# Apache Kafka on Github

Tags: github, message-queue, apache-kafka

Are there some good demo project using Apache Kafka (version 0.8 is preferred) on Github (or somewhere else)? We've been testing it with some toy projects. But I'd like to check out some real-world bigger projects.

Answer (score 4):

Toy projects are as good as demo projects. It will be fun writing your own simple producers/consumers. You can create your own demo project (and while doing so you will learn a lot). Think of a problem where you require large amount of say streaming data (Think logs of a running application). Now make Kafka to read those Logs. Kafka is just a kind of message queue. Until and unless you write your consumers I don't think there will be any fun. So for a real world consumer pickup say Twitter Storm. Send all the log lines of your application to the brokers where the Storm Consumer (Aka Kafka Spout) picks up those lines and send them to Bolts (Spout/Bolt are Storm terminology similar to Map Reduce but for real time).

This way you will have a full fledged demo application.

Now the main question. How to generate logs to feed to Kafka (for a demo project, if you dont have any application). There are plenty of huge data sets available (open source). From Youtube to Amazon to Twitter, all provide them. Just download it and think of some application. For example consider Youtube video logs (http://netsg.cs.sfu.ca/youtubedata/). Simulate as if they are coming online. Input them to Kafka. Let Storm Consumer (or Kafka Spout) pick that log line for you from the Kafka broker. Give each line of log to Bolt where in say the bolt just reads the line (do some analytics) and calculates the hottest/trending genres for videos watched in last X minutes.

Writing all of this should not take much time. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

i have been using kafka from quite sometime. i am using [franz-kafka](https://github.com/dannycoates/franz-kafka) nodejs client to implement pubsubhubbub spec.

i too didn't find any projects using kafka but you can ask me any questions that you have, i will try to answer them.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus
uses the 0.8 build